# too few arguments for class template "std::pair" : Passing std pair as arguments in varidiac function

Tags: c++, stl, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I have to pass `std::pair` of `std::string` to a variadic function. `std::pair` shows error `too few arguments for class template "std::pair"` when trying to access `std::pair` using `va_arg` macro.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
using std::pair;
using std::string;

bool EncodeJSonData(pair<string,string> inbulkData ...)
{     
    va_list args; 
    va_start(args, inbulkData);
    int count = 5;
    while(count--)
    { 
        pair<string,string> bulkData;
        bulkData = va_arg(args, pair<string,string>);  //here is the error      
    }
    va_end(args); 

    return true;
}
```

What is missing here,

Comment: Have you considered passing a container (e.g., vector) of pairs? A C variadic function will let the user pass whatever type they want without the compiler catching it. In addition, it's not guaranteed to work for C++ strings (including pairs of such) and most other interesting classes.

Comment: Please don't use variadic functions in C++. Instead, use variadic templates which are at least type safe.

Comment: Include all the headers required.

Comment: How is that supposed to terminate? Read this: [MCVE]

Comment: There is no portable way to use varargs to pass `std::pair<std::string,std::string>`. The type is non-trivial. Vararg is a relic of the past.  Use variadic templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`va_arg` is a macro, and character like the `','` may cause the macro parsing failed

So the solution is typedef the `pair<string,string>`:

```
    typedef pair<string, string> StrStrPair;
    StrStrPair bulkData;
    bulkData = va_arg(args, StrStrPair);
```

Comment: There is no portable way to use varargs to pass std::pair<std::string,std::string>. The type is non-trivial.